# jQuery Datepicker not disabling 2012 dates

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

2012 dates are not getting disabled and I cannot figure out why, I've tried every date format too with no joy - any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var unavailableDates = ["27-12-2011", "28-12-2011", "29-12-2011", "03-01-2012", "09-01-2012", "26-01-2012", "14-02-2012"];
    function unavailable(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                beforeShowDay: unavailable,
                minDate: 0
      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leading zeros were your downfall: http://jsfiddle.net/zvKPe/